# Copy product name to attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, magento1.9.3.1

I have a Magento store with 4000 products and i'm trying to create an xml file in order to register with a comparison service but i have a small problem. They want me to include in xml an MPN number (Manufacturer part number). For all products in my store I have a product name which is consisted of two or three words, brand name and MPN and i would like to copy the last word to an attribute value with name mpn.
I have some knowledge of SQL but i'm fairly new to Magento.
Magento 1.9.3.1
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try out following script.

i have consider mpn as attribute code.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $_product) 
{
    echo "</br>".'updating '.$_product->getSku()."</br>";
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
    $str =  $_product->getName();
    $lastWord = substr($str, strrpos($str, ' ') + 1);
    $product->setData('mpn', $lastWord )->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'mpn');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do i save this as php file and run it? If i want to copy only the last word of the name to attribute field will this work?

Comment: yes it will fetch last word from product name and set to the mpn attribute